# Is there any physical difference between the absence of a force and a force with a magnitude of 0

Tags: forces

Is there some sort of experiment one could perform that would differentiate between the absence of a force and a force with a magnitude of 0? Or are they just different ways of describing the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

"Absence of force" and "zero force" are just two different ways to describe the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Kinematatticaly they are the same but dynamically, there will be stresses built up in the object experiencing a net force of zero. Consider a spring for example, when you pull on its ends, even though the force is zero, there are still stresses in it.